# Create a new FaceBook page via the FB api

Tags: facebook, api

Is it possible to build a new Facebook page via the api?

I can't find any documentation regarding this. I presume it would just be a matter of passing in an email address and password to register then passing in any profile info/data.

I'm not particularly looking for a how-to-guide just would like to know if it's possible and for someone to point in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't create pages with any of the Facebook APIs. You can only do this through the user interface on facebook.com.

Comment: Thanks for the succinct answer. Exactly what I was looking for.